# Why the method turn is undefined for the type Finch?

Tags: java, finch

```
import edu.cmu.ri.createlab.terk.robot.finch.Finch;

public static void turn(String[] args){
    Finch myf = new Finch();
    myf.turn(30,30);

    myf.quit();
    System.exit(0);
}
```

I don't understand why turn comes up with an error as in the java docs turn is a method.

Comment: There's no `turn` method [here](http://www.finchrobot.com/javadoc/edu/cmu/ri/createlab/terk/robot/finch/Finch.html).

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the JavaDoc for *your* version?

Comment: http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/tlauwers/Finch/finch/Finch.html

Comment: You're not looking at the right documentation. This is `finch.Finch`.

Comment: According to the link there is one but maybe I haven't implemented it correctly anyone have a solution??

Comment: How do I use the finch.Finch because there is no other methods to rotate the finch by a set number of degrees that I know of